# Clarification on basics of OOP in JS and understanding variable scope in objects

Tags: javascript, oop, knockout.js, magento2

I am trying to understand Magento 2's way of using knockoutJs and requireJs. This has brought me to a wider question of trying to understand how variable scope works within objects? 
Look at this code picked up directly from Magento 2:

```
define([
    'ko',
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/template/loader',
    'mage/template'
], function (ko, $, templateLoader, template) {
    'use strict';

    var blockLoaderTemplatePath = 'ui/block-loader',
        blockContentLoadingClass = '_block-content-loading',
        blockLoader,
        blockLoaderClass,
        loaderImageHref;

    templateLoader.loadTemplate(blockLoaderTemplatePath).done(function (blockLoaderTemplate) {
        blockLoader = template($.trim(blockLoaderTemplate), {
            loaderImageHref: loaderImageHref
        });
        blockLoader = $(blockLoader);
        blockLoaderClass = '.' + blockLoader.attr('class');
    });

    /**
     * Helper function to check if blockContentLoading class should be applied.
     * @param {Object} element
     * @returns {Boolean}
     */
    function isLoadingClassRequired(element) {
        var position = element.css('position');

        if (position === 'absolute' || position === 'fixed') {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Add loader to block.
     * @param {Object} element
     */
    function addBlockLoader(element) {
        element.find(':focus').blur();
        element.find('input:disabled, select:disabled').addClass('_disabled');
        element.find('input, select').prop('disabled', true);

        if (isLoadingClassRequired(element)) {
            element.addClass(blockContentLoadingClass);
        }
        element.append(blockLoader.clone());
    }

    /**
     * Remove loader from block.
     * @param {Object} element
     */
    function removeBlockLoader(element) {
        if (!element.has(blockLoaderClass).length) {
            return;
        }
        element.find(blockLoaderClass).remove();
        element.find('input:not("._disabled"), select:not("._disabled")').prop('disabled', false);
        element.find('input:disabled, select:disabled').removeClass('_disabled');
        element.removeClass(blockContentLoadingClass);
    }

    return function (loaderHref) {
        loaderImageHref = loaderHref;
        ko.bindingHandlers.blockLoader = {
            /**
             * Process loader for block
             * @param {String} element
             * @param {Boolean} displayBlockLoader
             */
            update: function (element, displayBlockLoader) {
                element = $(element);

                if (ko.unwrap(displayBlockLoader())) {
                    addBlockLoader(element);
                } else {
                    removeBlockLoader(element);
                }
            }
        };
    };
});
```

If someone could explain the OOP concept at play here and how these functions are part of a single class would be great.Also, any pointers on classes and objects in JS would be great!

Comment: `explain the OOP concept at play here` - easy, there is no OOP concept at play here ... pointers on classes - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes ... pointers on objects - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object ... p.s. the only "class" referenced in the code is CSS class related

Comment: ok cool, and this case it is just functions inside of functions?

Comment: Classes and functions in javascript are basically the same thing. A class is just a function that returns an object made up of variables, and yes, other functions. That's also why the keyword "this" is so hard to grasp at times. Since there isn't really the normal concept of a class "this" becomes the context of the currently executing function.